# Reload fragment when onTabReselected android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, reselect

I has a TabNews extent extends Fragment
And when this tab reselected, I want reload this tab,
How can do it?

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 3) {
        //How can reload?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i resloved. Just use:
public static WebView webViewNews; -> in TabNews
and recall: 
TabNews.webViewNews.loadUrl(Constants.API_TAB_NEWS); -> in MainActivity